# UISearchBar is not extending its background color under the UIStatusBar in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have an UIViewController with a UICollectionView in it, and a UISearchBar on top of it. The problem is that when I tap on my search bar, and it hides the navigation bar, search bar background color is not extending under the status bar.

Here is how I set up the UISearchBar and UISearchController:

```
UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[ADC_SEARCH_RESULTS_CONTROLLER_IDENT copy]];
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0);
[self.view insertSubview:self.searchController.searchBar belowSubview:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
SuggestionResultsTVC *vc = (SuggestionResultsTVC *)searchResultsController.topViewController;
vc.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
self.searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Here is a screen shot of the UIViewController when search bar is dismissed:
http://s4.postimg.org/x0rncg5e5/Screen_Shot_2015_09_02_at_5_09_41_PM.png

And here is a screen shot of the view controller when search bar is active:
http://s4.postimg.org/tv71m8mrx/Screen_Shot_2015_09_02_at_5_10_04_PM.png

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard or xib file, go to Attributes Inspector -> Simulated metrics and change status bar from "inferred" to "none".

[image]

Comment: I don't want to hide status bar, I just want to make that background color, or the color of the object that is under it the same as the search bar's color.
Anyway I tried and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I build the app in simulator, and activated the UISearchBar, then I enter the "View UI Hierarchy" option in xcode, here is a screen where you can find it: 
http://s16.postimg.org/wyb8jxqw5/Screen_Shot_2015_09_02_at_5_47_58_PM.png

And there it was clear for me that the gray background color comes from a UIDimmingView under my UIViewController  -> the solution was to change the color of the UIView of my UIViewController, that is above that UIDimmingView to the color matching UISearchBar background.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your UISearchBar may send a call to its parent's UINavigationController after being tapped. So try tinkering with this:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```